# How to publish expo app that can be accessed by anyone, anywhere using QR code?

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, build, expo, mobile-application

after completing the development of an expo app, I want to share it with friends who can check it by  QR code or link to a live server. How can I do it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Expo Managed workflow, you can share your application with Expo Go. In this case, you don't need to publish in any store. Follow the instructions from section [Share a development build with your team](https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/share-with-your-team/). With this, you can use the [Expo Dashboard](https://expo.dev/) to deploy a project and share the URL or the QR Code to scan by the Expo Go App. I created an Expo project to share with a [link that contains the QR code](https://expo.dev/@marcelofreires/sharing-by-expo-go?serviceType=eas&distribution=expo-go&scheme=exp%2Bsharing-by-expo-go&channel=main&sdkVersion=48.0.0) to run on Expo Go.

> Note: To see the Expo application you must to install Expo Go.

Comment: what did you use to generate this shareable QR code? i can't find any instructions for this

Comment: The documentation currently doesn't have information about publishing to Expo Go.

Comment: Hey, guys! I updated the answer with a new link about sharing the project from the Expo Dashboard. The instructions were removed from the **Share pre-release versions of your app** section on this [commit](https://github.com/expo/expo/commit/5454078c216e264710190c2d6dd38c2daea68704#diff-6931473ca7f190912506da75e97bd3bceb2f1e6d5edc440bd3814a144ec3bfacL12-L29).

Comment: @alpere, thanks for your point about the old documentation. I updated the answer with the new link.

Comment: @marcelofreires still not able to get how to generate QR